# sql like command

Tags: sql

Using Like operator, how to retrieve a name which is having exact 100 characters

note: I don't want to use 100 underscores _
ex:

```
select ename from emp where ename like '_____________';
```

it should not like above 
is there any other way

Comment: It is not clear what you asking. please add some sample data. Wich DBMS do you use?

Comment: Why do you need the Like expression? you should use Like only when you want to search for a specific sub string within other string. Use Len() function to get exact count

Comment: actually it is not exatly 100 characters and above 100 and above or 500 characters and above finally what i need is above 500 means we should mention 500 underscores and followed by %

Comment: So which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? A regular expression would make this quite easy ("*SQL*" is **not** a DBMS product, it's a query language)

Comment: What do you want then? Either you want exactly 100 characters or not. Why isn't `LEN(x)=100` or `LEN(x)=@lengthParam` enough?

Comment: Does leading or trailing spaces count? And what about spaces between words?

Comment: So to get this straight: You want to select all names that exceed a certain length, no matter what characters the name contains, right?

Answer (score 2):

For exactly 100 characters , do

```
select ename from emp where LEN(ename)=100
```

For greater than equal to 100 characters

```
select ename from emp where LEN(ename) >= 100
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal _ is a wildcard character indicating any one character

Comment: To match underscore character you have to escape it `select ename from emp where LEN(ename)=100 and ename like '%[_]%`

Comment: `%[_]%` will match strings that have a `[` followed by any character, followed by a `]` anywhere in them. In (standard) SQL the `[` has no special meaning for the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: he can use escaping mechanism implemented in whichever databse is using , the idea was to indicate about escaping

Answer (score 0):

```
    select ename from emp where LEN(ename)=100 and ename like '%_%';
```

LEN is used for length of value and % before and after character means any string which contains atleast one _

for more that ore equal to 100

```
select ename from emp where LEN(ename)>=100 and ename like '%_%';
```

Comment: i went wrong actually it is not exactly 100 characters it is 100 characters and above

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
WHERE column_name REGEXP [a-z0-9]{100}
```

Comment: Only if the OP uses MySQL. Oracle would be a better assumption - `emp` is a table name encountered in Oracle samples.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: in Oracle it would be `regexp_like`

Answer (score 0):

Many dbms products support the REPEAT function (not ANSI however...)

```
select ename from emp where ename like repeat('_',100)
```

Or use CHAR_LENGTH:

```
select ename from emp where CHAR_LENGTH(ename) = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what DBMS you using, this is should work under mysql :

```
select ename from emp where ename like concat('%', REPEAT('_',100),'%');
```

Above condition is where string have 100 `UNDERSCORE` whether in beginning, middle or end of string. For condition where string exactly have 100 `UNDERSCORE` :

```
select ename from emp where ename = REPEAT('_',100);
```